# How to trigger Email notification to Group of users from BigQuery on threshold?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-workflows

I have written the below query in `GCP BigQuery`, where I am using error function to pop-up error message when the threshold for the quantity column exceeds 1000.

```
SELECT ERROR(CONCAT("Over threshold: ", CAST(quantity AS STRING)))
FROM `proj.dataset.table` 
WHERE quantity > 1000
```

I am getting the email notification when I have scheduled this query in `BigQuery`. But I want to trigger that notification to the group of users through BigQuery.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Really interesting use case, I've learnt something new today. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging_functions

Comment: Is the error is logged in Cloud Logging? If so you can set up a Alert with Cloud Alerting on this log entry.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this and a lot more with the [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) serverless product and an external email sending provider such as Sendgrid, Mailchimp, Mailgun that offers a REST Api.

You basically setup a Workflow that will handle the steps for you:

- run the BigQuery query
- on error trigger an email step
- you could even combine, if results returned are of a `kind` execute another step

The main workflow would be like this:

```
#workflow entrypoint
main:
  steps:
    - getList:
        try:
          call: BQ_Query
          args:
            query: SELECT ERROR('demo') from (select 1) where 1>0
          result: result
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - sendEmail:
                call: sendGridSend
                args:
                  secret: sendgrid_email_dev_apikey
                  from: from@domain.com
                  to: 
                     - email: email1@domain.com
                     - email: email2@domain.com 
                  subject: "This is a test"
                  content: ${"Error message from BigQuery" + e.body.error.message}
                  contentType: "text/plain"
                result: callResult
    - final:
        return: ${callResult}
```

`sendgrid_email_dev_apikey` is the secret label, I've used [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/) to store Sendgrid's API key. If you want to use MailChimp there are examples in [this Github repo](https://github.com/filipknapik/google_workflows/tree/master/connectors).

The workflow invoker could be a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/schedule-workflow) entry. So instead of launching the scheduled queries from BigQuery interface, you set them up in a scheduled Workflow. You must give permission for the invoker `service account` to read Secrets, to run BigQuery jobs.

The rest of the Workflow is here:

```
BQ_Query:
  params: [query]
  steps:
    - runBQquery:
        call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
        args:
          projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
          body:
            useLegacySql: false
            query: ${query}
        result: queryResult
    - documentFound:
        return: ${queryResult}
sendGridSend:
  params: [secret, from, to, subject, content, contentType]
  steps:
    - getSecret:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: ${"https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER") + "/secrets/" + secret + "/versions/latest:access"}
          auth:
            type: OAuth2
        result: sendGridKey
    - decodeSecrets:
        assign:
          - decodedKey: ${text.decode(base64.decode(sendGridKey.body.payload.data))}
    - sendMessage:
        call: http.post
        args:
          url: https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send
          headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
            Authorization: ${"Bearer " + decodedKey }
          body:
            personalizations:
              - to: ${to}
            from:
              email: ${from}
            subject: ${subject}
            content:
              - type: ${contentType}
                value: ${content}
        result: sendGridResult
    - returnValue:
        return: ${sendGridResult}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you receive a mail notification, I guess you are using the BigQuery Data Transfer service.

According to [this paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications#email_notifications) only the person that set up the transfer will receive the mail notification. However, if you're using Gmail you can automatically forward these message to a list of users.

[This link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en#zippy=%2Conly-forward-certain-kinds-of-messages%2Cforward-to-multiple-accounts) should guide you through it.